# Postgresql trigger function not working

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I'm very new to trigger function. Actually this is the first time I'm using it, and I can't pass over an issue. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION altitude()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
 maxaltimeter DOUBLE PRECISION;

BEGIN

  SELECT max(altitude) INTO maxaltimeter FROM waypoints WHERE flight_id = OLD.id;
  RETURN NEW;
  UPDATE flights SET max_altimeter = NEW.maxaltimeter WHERE id=OLD.id;


END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER set_altitude
  AFTER UPDATE OF status
  ON flights
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE altitude();
```

When running UPDATE on the 'flights' table (status column) I don't get any results (but no errors too). Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the statements in the wrong order. The `RETURN NEW` will terminate the trigger and thus the update will not be run.

It should be:

```
SELECT max(altitude) INTO maxaltimeter FROM waypoints WHERE flight_id = OLD.id;
UPDATE flights SET max_altimeter = NEW.maxaltimeter WHERE id=OLD.id;
RETURN NEW;
```

But I hope you are aware that this is not going to be a scalable solution.

Usually it's better to not store calculated/aggregated values in the database, but to calculate them while you retrieve the data. For convenience you might want to create a view that returns you the max() value for each flight.

The only reason why pre-calculating such a value would be if the retrieval is **really** expensive and you have to do it *very* often compared to the updates and the retrieval performance is more important than the update performance.

Comment: thank you! It worked like a charm! Also, thanks for the suggestion regarding the view. I created a view with the max(altitude) and select from there the maxaltimeter.

Comment: Also take into account that the trigger can result in quadratic behaviour: if N records with the same flight_id are updated, the MAX() aggregate will be invoked N times, and each invocation needs to inspect (N+x) tuples. You could reduce the load a bit by bailing out early if new.altitude happens to be smaller than the current max_altimeter (which is most often the case)